# Python fizzbuzz not giving correct output

Tags: python, fizzbuzz

My fizzbuzz code keeps giving me none as an output i dont know why please help.

Here is my code:

```
def FizzBuzz(num):
  for num in range (1,50):
   string = ""
  if num % 3 == 0:
     string = string + "Fizz"
  if num % 5 == 0:
     string = string + "Buzz"
  if num % 5 != 0 and  num % 3 != 0:
    string = string + str(num)
    print (string)
 
print FizzBuzz(raw_input())
```

Comment: Could it be because the indentation of all the if statements are wrong? They should be part of the for loop body. Also, the last print should not be inside an if statement at all. The reason you're getting None is because FizzBuzz doesn't return anything, so printing its output prints what it returns: None.

Comment: You seem to expect `FizzBuzz` to return something; where in your code do you think you make that happen?

Comment: Also, avoid CamelCase as function's name, they usually are used for class name.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to write `def FizzBuzz(max_num): for num in range(1, max_num + 1) :`

Comment: Remember `raw_string` returns a `str`, you might want to convert it into `int`.

Comment: If you're using `raw_input()` it means you're still using Python 2.x, which has been EOL for several years. You should upgrade to 3.x.

Comment: Can you write it for me so i can see please

Comment: There are many fizzbuzz questions here, you can simply search for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not used proper intendation in the code.

```py
   print FizzBuzz(raw_input())
```

This statement doesn't print anything because the FizzBuzz function is not returning any value to the function call. (*None* is taken as return value)

````py
def FizzBuzz(num):
    for num in range (1,50):
        string = ""
        if num % 3 == 0:
            string = string + "Fizz"
        if num % 5 == 0:
            string = string + "Buzz"
        if num % 5 != 0 and  num % 3 != 0:
            string = string + str(num)
        print (string)
FizzBuzz(raw_input()) # function call (no need to use print statement as nothing is returned```
````